# How do I prevent auto loading of blank notebook at startup?

Tags: front-end

I'm using Mathematica 8 with operating system Mac OS X Lion.  When I open Mathematica it always loads a blank notebook.  I don't want it to load anything by default.

In the Preferences pane there is a tab for Appearance.  Near the bottom of the tabview there is an option

"Show at startup"

with a drop down menu.  There is no option for not showing anything at startup.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows, you set `InitialUntitledNotebook` to `False` in the `Global Options > PrivateFrontEndOptions` section of the `Option Inspector` to prevent a `Untitled-1` notebook opening at start-up. You can also supress/show the welcome splash screen.The combination `"ShowAtStartup"->"New Document"` and `"InitialUntitledNotebook"->False"` gives just the MMA toolbar at startup.

[image: option inspector start up]

Comment: This appears to be a bug for the Mac OS X version of Mathematica 8.  I did this but when I load Mathematica it just hangs.  I use multiple desktops. When I slide to the next desktop, one that I didn't load Mathematica in, and then go back Mathematica is no longer hanging and a blank  notebook shows up.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: works fine on snow leopard.

Comment: This looks much cleaner than my old kludge, though I know that mine worked since version 4.  This appears to have been added in Version 8.

Comment: I'm using Lion.  I should have stated this.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that there is a better option in version 8; use that if you have it.  For older versions:

I was bothered by having Mathematica start with a blank notebook open.  I could close this notebook with a script, but it would still flash open briefly.  My hack is to create a file `Invisible.nb` containing:

```
Notebook[{},Visible->False]
```

And add this to my `Kernel\init.m` :

```
If[Length[Notebooks["Invisible*"]] > 0, 
  NotebookClose[Notebooks["Invisible*"][[1]]]
]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  Options[$FrontEnd, NotebooksMenu] /. 
    HoldPattern["Invisible.nb" -> {__}] :> Sequence[]
]
```

This closes the invisible Notebook after *Mathematica* starts.  Normally it would not be a problem, but this is "good housekeeping" and there are some packages or tools that I have seen that rely on `Notebooks[]`.  Furthermore, if `Invisible.nb` somehow got focus and something was pasted into it that would be confusing.

I now start Mathematica by opening `Invisible.nb`