# Simple question about startup options

Tags: interface, kernel-startup

This is probably fairly straightforward, but I wasn't able to find it right away. I'd like for Mathematica to display on startup the latest notebook I was working on, and nothing else. No additional old notebooks and no new blank notebook. There is probably an option hiding somewhere to do that, but I wasn't able to find it. Apologies if this is too simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R.M beat me but I'll post this anyway for variety.

You can open the last Notebook with:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, NotebooksMenu][[1, 2, -1, 2, 1]] // NotebookOpen
```

Methods for preventing the opening of a blank Notebook, for both version 7 and 8 are here:

[How do I prevent auto loading of blank notebook at startup?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1383/121)

Answer (score 6):

The list of recently opened notebooks (as shown in `File > Open Recent`) is saved in the `NotebooksMenu` option for `$FrontEnd`, arranged by ascending absolute time (i.e., most recent is last). So the most recent notebook can be opened with:

```
Last[NotebooksMenu /. Options@$FrontEnd] /. 
    HoldPattern[_ -> {file_, ___}] :> NotebookOpen@file
```

Some additional related questions that might of interest are:

- [How do I prevent auto loading of blank notebook at startup?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1383/121)
- [Launch a specific notebook automatically when Mathematica starts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8316/5)

Comment: Thanks, I always get the last notebook opened, I was mainly interested in avoiding the automatic opening of all other notebooks, especially the blank one.

Comment: @Moshe that is answered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1383/121

Comment: @Moshe Mr.Wizard's link answers that specific question. A complementary question then, is to open just a specific notebook each and every time. That is answered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8316/5

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks, I'll take a look. Maybe my question can be closed as a duplicate then.